# how do I access function of Data.js from a controller CandidateCtrl.js in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm new in `Javascript` and `AngularJS`, I have a function named 'getdata()' which is defined in 'Data.js' file which retruns some data in the 'json' format. I want to access this function(getData() with return values) from my controller named 'CandidateCtrl.js'. How can I do that?.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Without code and/or a plunker/jsfiddle, it's difficult to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use angular `services` to achieve it.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory('Data', function() {

    var data = {
        // Your object
        name: 'Joe',
        age: 24
    };
    // You can also get data from data.js. 
    // Assume that `getdata` function available in data.js 
    // var data = getdata();
    return data;
});

app.controller('MyController', function($scope, Data) {
    $scope.data = Data;
});
```